# How to do one dict into list of multi dict? Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I would like to convert from json data to key value format, how to do?

My data

```
data = { 
  "type": "student",
  "age": "17",
  "sex": "male",
}
```

Expected Output

```
[ 
  { "type": "student", "key": "age", "value": "17"  },
  { "type": "student", "key": "sex", "value": "male"  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a function to generalize your output in case your dictionary have more keys that you want to key as they are or add then to your list of key value pair

```py
def transfrom(data, non_key_value: list, key_value: list):
    base = {key: val for key, val in data.items() if key in non_key_value}
    ouput = [{**base, **{"key": val, "value": data[val]}} for val in key_value]
    return ouput
```

```
transfrom(data, non_key_value=["type"], key_value=["age", "sex"])
>>>
[{'type': 'student', 'key': 'age', 'value': '17'},
 {'type': 'student', 'key': 'sex', 'value': 'male'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with json and there might be a function in the `json` package for this conversion, but this works for your data:

```
data = { 
  "type": "student",
  "age": "17",
  "sex": "male",
}

out = []

for key, value in data.items():
    d = {"type": data["type"]}
    if key != "type":
        d["key"] = key
        d["value"] = value
        out.append(d)
out
```

Out:

```
[{'type': 'student', 'key': 'age', 'value': '17'},
 {'type': 'student', 'key': 'sex', 'value': 'male'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with the [pop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) method and the `|` operator:

```
data = {"type": "student", "age": "17", "sex": "male"}
base = {"type": data.pop("type")}
output = [base | {"key": key, "value": value} for key, value in data.items()]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'type': 'student', 'key': 'age', 'value': '17'}, {'type': 'student', 'key': 'sex', 'value': 'male'}]
```

This code uses the pop method to remove the key from the dictionary and return it, which means that "base" becomes `{"data": "student"}` and "data" becomes `{"age": "17", "sex": "male"}`.

It then uses a list comprehension iterating over the remaining keys and values in "data", using the `|` operator to combine them with the key/value pair in "base" each time to create a new dictionary.

Note: the `|` operator was introduced in Python 3.9.